# How to configure php myadmin(id password) through bitnami testlink 1.9.14 stack?

Tags: phpmyadmin, bitnami, testlink

[image]

phpmyadmin login page error when I try to login with this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here,

The default user for the phpMyAdmin application is "root" and the password is the same that you set during the installation. If you are using the Virtual Appliance or the AMI the default password is "bitnami".

I hope it helps.

Regards,

Fran